# Matlab Put Labels on Clusters

Tags: matlab, plot

I have implemented an algorithm and here is a plot from my resource book:

[image]

I am new to Matlab. I have a xValues list, yValues list (I have divided my final matrix into x and y axis, I am not sure is that true, if you make a suggestion you are welcome) and a vector of labels.

I want to get an image as like in the above. How can I put some class labels (i.e. 0,1,2,3..) as like given image?

**PS:** I plot as like that: `plot(xValues,yValues,'b.');` however my dots are like diamond, not point as like in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text` to plot text on the scene. (Matlab help:)

```
text(X,Y,'string') adds the text in the quotes to location (X,Y)
on the current axes, where (X,Y) is in units from the current
plot.
```

You will need to know where on the graph you want to plot your text but you can do this:

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;
y = sin(x);
p = plot(x,y)

text(-pi/4,sin(-pi/4),'7')
text(-pi/4+1,sin(-pi/4),sprintf('%d', 8))
text(-pi/4+2,sin(-pi/4),'9')
```

which will give you this:

[image]

You can add different text styles etc with the regular matlab annotation things. You can also automatic add the number you want for your cluster with the sprintf command as i have shown when i plot the 8.

Good luck.

Comment: It seems me something different used at image at question. It looks like the person who plotted the image didn't put them into image 1 by 1 with some function i.e. text. There are class labels i.e. 0 nearly overlapped so it looks like Matlab put them automatically.

Comment: @kamaci I don't think so, i have never seen a function do that, but it might be some custom function including `text`, also you can overlap the numbers just by making there position in X and Y close together.

Comment: You may be right, I mean the person who wants to put labels by hand may not want to put overlapped labels.

Comment: @kamaci It would be easy to write a function to do what you are asking if you expand on the question. Where should the numbers be in reference to the data (X and Y list). What should the numbers be or what do they represent?

Comment: @kamaci Just for reference, [Matlab agree with Ben's (+1) solution](http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/solutions/en/data/1-SW4AT/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-SW4AT)

Comment: I could do it with your answer and reference. I don't show every class labels, just some of them.